# Why is my factorial program using recursion not working

Tags: c

I am new to coding. so I wanted to write a c program using recursion to calculate the factorial of a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int a) {
  int n = 1;

  if (a != 0)
    return;
  else
    n = n * a;
  a--;
  fact(a);
  return n;
}

int main() {
  printf("%d", fact(5));
  return 0;
}
```

This is the program I have written. I know this is probably wrong but I think I would understand programming better if I was able to understand why the above program is exactly wrong.

Comment: Please, format your code.

Comment: Read your `fact` function top to bottom. What does it do? Suppose `a` is 5. What happens? What do you want to happen?

Comment: I think it is time to learn to use a debugger. If you did, you would immediately see that `if(a!=0)
        return;` causes the function to return immediately. In addition,**warnings are not to be ignored**. This line should raise a warning because it returns nothing while the function is declared to return an int value.

Comment: Pay attention to compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4):

Because whenever you pass any value other than 0 to `fact` your code exits without even returning a value:

```
if(a!=0)
    return;
```

You should get at least a warning from your compiler that this is invalid code, since `fact` is expected to always return an `int` value.

But even more so, this is a logical error.

Did you mean to write:

```
if (a == 0) return 1; //0! = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

[Lev M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10302746/lev-m) pointed out your mistakes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66767122/14947044). This is a working recursive implementation of the factorial algorithm.

```
unsigned int fac(unsigned char n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    return n * fac(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: @GovindParmar I have now changed the input type to an `unsigned char`.